# Create setup with InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield-2010

I want to create setup for my winform .net application with installshield 2010.I know the steps and i have created a setup with it which works fine.

But my application need several resources to run successfully and i want to know if there is any standard way to add these resources to the setup instead of adding them to the same folder with the .exe files like what i have done in my setup?

Note that i am beginner in installshield so please give me a complete tutorial of working with this software if you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add files and folders using the files explorer:

1. In the View list under **Specify Application Data**, click **Files**.
2. In the **Feature** list, select the feature with which you want the file associated.
3. In the **Destination computer’s folders** pane, right-click **Destination Computer** and then click the predefined folder that you want to use.
4. If you need to create a further folder hierarchy, right-click the predefined folder, click **Add**, and provide a name for the folder. Repeat as necessary.
5. In the **Destination computer’s folders** pane, click the folder into which you want to place the file.
6. In the **Source computer’s folders** pane, navigate to the folder containing the file you want to add.
7. Select and drag the file you want to add from the **Source computer’s files** pane to the **Destination computer’s files** pane.

Click [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/isxhelp17/IHelpISXFilesExplorer.htm) to more detail.

About tutorial: [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/Tutorials.htm)

Hope it help you.